# Return undefined with a method inside a javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class with a simple method that have a firestore call, that it's async I think.
The problem is that when I call this method, it returns undefined and I don't know how to implement a callback function for return the array I need.

The code of my class is:

```
class Alumnes {
    llista(ordre) {
      db.collection('alumnes')
        .orderBy('cognoms', ordre)
        .get()
        .then(function (doc) {
            var llistaAlumnes = [];
            doc.forEach((doc) => {
                llistaAlumnes.push(doc.data().nom + ' ' + doc.data().cognoms);
            });
            return llistaAlumnes;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

And I call it with this code:

```
var alumnes = new Alumnes();
var llistaAlumnes = alumnes.llista('asc');
console.log(' llistaAlumnes', llistaAlumnes);
```

But it returns *undefined* ever because firestore use async functions.
How can I set llistaAlumnes after firestore ends call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get some results from function it has to `return` something. In your case you should return the promise like this

```
class Alumnes {
  llista(ordre) {
    return db.collection('alumnes')
      .orderBy('cognoms', ordre)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        var llistaAlumnes = [];
        doc.forEach((doc) => {
          llistaAlumnes.push(doc.data().nom + ' ' + doc.data().cognoms);
        });
        return llistaAlumnes;
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```

Then you can find out the results, but remeber to get it in asynchronous manner as the call to the db is not instant

```
var alumnes = new Alumnes();
var llistaAlumnes = alumnes.llista('asc');
llistaAlumnes.then(res => {
   console.log(' llistaAlumnes', res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. Simple and perfect solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try use async/await

```js
class Alumnes {
    async llista(ordre) {
        var alumnes = db.collection('alumnes').orderBy('cognoms', ordre);

        try {
            var allAlumnes = await alumnes.get();
            var llistaAlumnes = [];
            allAlumnes.forEach((doc) => {
                llistaAlumnes.push(doc.data().nom + ' ' + doc.data().cognoms);

            });
            return llistaAlumnes;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It returns a Promise, but I'm new in this async method and I don't know how to get then the complete array. I see now the next comment and I can get all array content! Thanks again!